# Convert PHP file To PDO

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, pdo

i am beginer to php and i need your help.i want to make the following code to PDO to have a json output for an android app i am trying to bulit.I tryed a lot of solution but nothing correct came because of the JSON responce.I couldn also find good example and tutorials.Also i am new as i said with php so i am afraid to try complicated scenarios

here is the php code

This is my Config file

db_config.php

```
<?php

define('DB_USER', "root"); // db user
define('DB_PASSWORD', ""); // db password (mention your db password here)
define('DB_DATABASE', "androidhive"); // database name
define('DB_SERVER', "localhost"); // db server
?>
```

This is connection file

```
db_connect.php
<?php


class DB_CONNECT {

    // constructor
    function __construct() {
        // connecting to database
        $this->connect();
    }

    // destructor
    function __destruct() {
        // closing db connection
        $this->close();
    }

    /**
     * Function to connect with database
     */
    function connect() {
        // import database connection variables
        require_once __DIR__ . '/db_config.php';

        // Connecting to mysql database
        $con = mysql_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD) or die(mysql_error());

        // Selecing database
        $db = mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE) or die(mysql_error()) or die(mysql_error());

        // returing connection cursor
        return $con;
    }

    /**
     * Function to close db connection
     */
    function close() {
        // closing db connection
        mysql_close();
    }

}

?>
```

get_all_products.php

```
<?php

/*
 * Following code will list all the products
 */

// array for JSON response
$response = array();

// include db connect class
require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

// connecting to db
$db = new DB_CONNECT();

// get all products from products table
$result = mysql_query("SELECT *FROM products") or die(mysql_error());

// check for empty result
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // looping through all results
    // products node
    $response["products"] = array();

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        // temp user array
        $product = array();
        $product["pid"] = $row["pid"];
        $product["name"] = $row["name"];
        $product["price"] = $row["price"];
        $product["created_at"] = $row["created_at"];
        $product["updated_at"] = $row["updated_at"];

        // push single product into final response array
        array_push($response["products"], $product);
    }
    // success
    $response["success"] = 1;

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
} else {
    // no products found
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "No products found";

    // echo no users JSON
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

I know is very easy for someone with experience but i am strungle with it.please help because i have a strick deadline and no time now for deaper search.Thank you

**Would it be helpfull if i post what i have done?I didnt post it for space reason**s

EDIT
THIS IS WHAT I HAVE DONE SO FAR ANY IDEAS?

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname;", $dbuser, $dbpass);
$query = "Select * FROM products";


//execute query

try {

    $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
    $result = $stmt->execute(HAVE NO IDEA!!!!);
}

catch (PDOException $ex) {
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Database Error!";
    die(json_encode($response));

}




$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
if ($rows) {
    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "Post Available!";
    $response["posts"]   = array();


    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        $post             = array();
        $post["pid"] = $row["pid"];
        $post["name"]    = $row["name"];
        $post["price"]  = $row["price"];


        //update our repsonse JSON data
        array_push($response["posts"], $post);

    }



    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);

} else {

    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "No Post Available!";
    die(json_encode($response));

}


?>
```

Comment: Strict deadlines, I know about those all too well. Nothing like last minute stuff.

Comment: Yeah and i think i am going to lose my mind!!hahah

Comment: Here's a link to [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements).

Comment: You don't use `execute()` against `query`, you use it against `prepared statements`. So in this case, the Query should just be `foreach($db->query($query) as $row):` The reason you use prepared statements is when you're accepting user input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this approach:

```
<?php
$response = array()
try {
    //connection
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname;", $dbuser, $dbpass);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    //prepare
    $query = "Select * FROM products";
    $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
    //get resutlt
    $result = $stmt->execute();
    if ($stmt->rowCount > 0) {
        $response["success"] = true;
        $response["message"] = "Post Available!";

        //populate post array
        while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
            $response["posts"][] = $row;
        }
    }else{
        $response["success"] = false;
        $response["message"] = "No Post Available!";    
    }
}

catch (PDOException $ex) {
    $response["success"] = false;
    $response["message"] = "Database Error!";  
}

echo json_encode($response);

?>
```

[**Prepared statements and stored procedures**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements)

---

using fetch all:

```
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
var_dump($rows);
$response["posts"] = $rows;
```

Comment: Thanks man but i have a Warning: array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given.any ideas?

Comment: try `$response['posts'][] = $row;` instead

Comment: OK MAN YOU ARE THE BEST!!!!!!IT WORKED!!!THANK YOU!!!can i ask a little favor?can you explain me the while loop how it works??

Comment: Sure the while loop, is using fetches one row at the times, not so different from fetchAll

Comment: "pid":"1",
"0":"1",
"name":"X-Men: Days of Future Past",
"1":"X-Men: Days of Future Past" this is my output and is duplicated.i just need the name and id.Any ideas?

Comment: Ok man thank you.Your solutin is just great!!!!!

Comment: Hey man i have an other problem with my script could you check my link if you want?thank you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25949537/pdo-output-utf8-insert

Comment: oh man you are really great!thank you very much i am begginer and i strungle with pdo and json.thanks again