# PDO output utf8 insert

Tags: mysql, json

I am trying to show some data with PDO to my browser but it shows an error like **??????????** in the output. I tried to put `$db -> exec('set names utf8')`; but it changed to:

> o 039c\u0395\u039d\u039f\u0399 \u03a0\u03a5\u03a1\u every

If I put English content to my database everything is working and the output okay but if I put Greek I get the problem, and I need greek inserts

Here is the output without `$db -> exec('set names utf8')`:

```
  "eventID":"3",
    "catID":"1",
    "poiID":"1",
    "eventSourceURL":"??????? ??? ??????? ",
    "eventTitle":"??????? ??? ??????? ",
    "eventDescr":null,
    "eventDate":"",
    "eventImage":null,
    "eventTime":null,
    "eventComments":null,
    "eventPreDescription":null

}
```

Here is my PDO

```
<?php 


require('db_params.php');


$response = array();
try {

    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname;", $dbuser, $dbpass);
    $db -> exec('set names utf8');
        $query = "select * from events where catID=1";
    $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);

    $result = $stmt->execute();

    if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
        $response["success"] = true;
        $response["message"] = "Post Available!";
        while($row = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

        $response["posts"]["pid"] = $row;
}
    }else{
        $response["success"] = false;
        $response["message"] = "No Post Available!";    
    }
}

catch (PDOException $ex) {
    $response["success"] = false;
    $response["message"] = "Database Error!";  
}

echo json_encode($response);
//$statement->closeCursor(); 
   //$pdoObject = null; 

?>
```

### Update

The solution is to just add JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE:

```
echo json_encode($response,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

Comment: You can use `utf8_encode()` because jsonencode only work with that encoding

Answer (score 0):

Since you are connecting to mysql database you can take advantage of the following attribute

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname;", $dbuser, $dbpass, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
```

And remove the `exec(set ..)`